# Sql server: strange value (rectangle, g and ASCII symbol)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I`m working with SQL SERVER 2008 in Management Studio. Select statement returned an empty string in one column:

[image]

But inside I`ve found strange values:

[image]

I would like to ask, what thoose values mean? 
Best regards

Comment: Are you trying to insert non-english characters (lime chinese, korean) in that column and data type is not set to NVARCHAR??

Comment: Why do you think "Select statement returned an **empty string** in one column"? Did you filter on len(my_field) = 0? Your column contains what was inserted in it. And we don't know what was inserted, maybe you know

Comment: Please tell more about the system we're looking at.  Can you share the data types for all the columns?  Can you tell us what data you expect to see?  And tell us the exact queries that produce the results in each picture.

Comment: @Raska
data type is set to varchar(40)

Comment: @sepupic
You are correct (select where coumn = '' returns 0 rows), its not an empty string but copy paste from that column to text editor fails.

Comment: @MikeM
Both coulumns are vachar
firts query is:

 select column1, column2 from table
second one is not a query, but view "Edit 200 rows" from Management Studio

Comment: @fafnir1990 -- As others have already started to suggest, that could be the problem.  If the application is inserting non-ascii values into those varchar columns, they will turn into junk like that.

Comment: @fafnir1990 -- Non-ascii includes things like Chinese, Russian, Arabic.

Comment: Ok, many thanks to everyone for suggestions :)

Comment: `varchar(40)` is not a complete data type specification.You also need the collation to know the character encoding (and character set). However, it does seem that @David might be [onto](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48641988/2226988) something: Is the data even text? BTW—A text renderer typically shows the white rectangle when the font doesn't support the character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values could be binary representations of numeric values, each being 2 greater than the previous value.
Execute this code and do "Edit top 200 rows"

```
create table stranGe ( A varchar(40), B varchar(40) )

go

declare @I int = 91901

while @I < 99999
  begin

    insert into StranGe ( A, B ) values ( cast(@I as varbinary), cast(@I as varchar) )

    set @I = @I + 2
  end

select * from stranGe
```

[image]

You might be able to get the original number back by casting to varbinary

```
select cast(A as varbinary), cast(cast(A as varbinary)as int) from stranGe
```